# Extract validation rules from a route

Tags: hapi.js

I am trying to build an endpoint like this `/schema?method=get&endpoint=/users/search` and the purpose is the provide a "JSONified" representation of the `Joi` validation I'm using. This will be used by the Front-End for client-side validation.

Is this even possible? Printing `server.table()` doesn't seem to have the information there.

I also welcome suggestion about how to name my schema route.

Comment: I store my schema in objects but if in json form could be stored in a database which can then be sent to client on request.  I don't know how you will do this with joi validation unless you dynamically generate routes from a defined schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`server.match()`](https://hapijs.com/api#servermatchmethod-path-host) (for route lookup) in combination with [`Joi.describe()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/545040431a44bd50215e60b3c73ea8340ebd3b9a/lib/any.js#L668) (for Joi schema description) to do what you want.